# rails 4 one_to_one relationship with scope and variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bar, ->(current_user) { where(user_id:current_user) }
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bar
end
```

I want to return the bar record associated with the foo and a user_id that I specify.

```
> Foo.first.bar(2)
SQL  =>  Foo Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos"  ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Bar Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."foo_id" = ? 
AND "bars"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1  [["foo_id", 1]]
```

It looks like it's taking the foo_id and passing it into the scope, but I want to specify that number myself when I call the method. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: If a Foo only has_one bar and a bar belongs_to a user then surely a Foo is only associated with 1 user ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
user_id = 2
Foo.bar(user_id)
```

Calling `.first` on `Foo` grabs the first `Foo` and then attempts to scope down from there. If the first `Foo` isn't what you're looking for then you're not gonna get anything.

But what RoyTheBoy is telling you is that if you have the user_id then you have the `User` so you should be able to get the `Foo` you are looking for with this:

```
User.find(user_id).bar.foo
```

And since you're looking for the `Bar` you really only need

```
User.find(user_id).bar
```